# Como fazer uma galeria do tipo mosaico

Tags: jquery

Bom pessoal, eu gostaria que alguém pudesse me indicar algum link ou me da uma luz de como fazer uma galeria tipo mosaico, como no link: http://todomundoodeiaochrisonline.blogspot.com.br/

Esse estilo ai é do blogspot e eu gostaria de algo parecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você estaria querendo um plugin jquery como esses?

1. http://masonry.desandro.com/
2. http://sapegin.github.io/jquery.mosaicflow/
3. http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/full_screen_preview/2281417
4. http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/

acredito que são bons exemplos.

Comment: Por mais que a resposta esteja nos **links**, acredito que somente eles não fornecem uma resposta a questão .Aconselho fazer um tipo de resumo, colocar exemplos e o código na resposta.
Se acaso os links forem desativados a resposta não será mais útil para futuros usuários.